# How to find atleast one field has the value in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a newbie to mongodb.I store JSON in mongodb and this JSON has the value fields
I want to find and return an array/record where atleast one field has value . Basically I want to find partially filled records where not all of its fields has a value .I am using Aggregates in Java.

This is how the document returned after querying for the records,I have the list of languages the user should be able to see let's say in this case(user has access to see en_US and en_FR)

```
tralation{
    env{
        mytext{
          en_US: "yes",
          en_FR: ""
        }myanothertext{
          en_US: "no"
        }
      }
}
```

In this data given for partial result I should get both records(mytext,myanothertext).

Comment: please provide what you have tried so far and structure of db and json as well

Comment: Added the document result stored in db